# eikon fingerprint reader for mac

Tags: osx-mavericks, fingerprint

Does any one know of a way to enable finger print login on osx mavericks (or osx Yosemite as it will be replacing mavericks) for a eikon usb reader? I'v been trying to find a way to use the normal truesuite but that dosent seem possible anymore, so maybe some other 3rd part software thats compatible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no good solutions.
Apple acquired AuthenTec, and apart from TouchID for iOS devices, there is seemingly no further development on the TrueSuite software that was Mac compatible.
I own four of the Eikon USC fingerprint readers which worked perfectly under Snow Leopard, but ceased working under Mavericks. 
You might post to Apple Communities to see if anyone there can offer a solution.